# Creating Global DynamoDB Table with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am creating dynamodb using json aws cloudformation. I need to make that table global by adding 3 more regions. Can we do that using CFT? or i can do only through UI/Console?

I am trying some blocks online but none of that helps.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/v1.14.0/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb-global

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for global tables in Cloudformation.It is yet another feature where Cloudformation support lags the feature itself. You would need to write a custom resource to do this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

I've written a few custom resources for similar situations and they are fairly straightforward to write.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a DynamoDB global tables, you have many option like using AWS console, AWS CLI and CloudFormation.

**AWS Console:**  When using AWS console, navigate to global table tab and add replicas in region of your choice and you are done. You can check my  [post](https://cloudkatha.com/how-to-create-dynamodb-global-table-using-aws-console/) on the same to see step by step process.

AWS CLI: Using AWS CLI, again you first create a DynamoDB table using CLI and then you add replica regions into it to make it a global table. Here is another [post](https://cloudkatha.com/how-to-create-dynamodb-global-table-using-aws-cli/)  by me to help you do it using CLI.

AWS CloudFormation: You can use AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable resource to create a DynamoDb global table using CloudFormation. Here is a small sample of how it  looks like-

```
  DemoDynamoDBGlobalTable: 
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable
Properties: 
  .............
  .............
  Replicas:
    - Region: !Ref ReplicaRegion1
    - Region: !Ref ReplicaRegion2
  .............
  .............
```

You can also check my post on how to [create DynamoDB global table using CloudFormation.](https://cloudkatha.com/how-to-create-dynamodb-global-table-using-cloudformation/)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will follow that from here after.

Comment: Is there any specific format that I need to follow. If you can enlighten me on that please.

Comment: No, there's no specific format. Mentioning "my post" as you have just done is sufficient for disclosure.

Comment: Thank you @cigien. It's helpful I will keep this in mind